# Eloquent saves missing attributes as empty strings instead of NULLs

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When I try to save a model with a missing attribute to a not-NULL db field, I don't want the application to be quiet about that, I want it to scream in vein. But it's being just fine with the empty strings that eloquent saves.

Why does `MyModel::create([])` succeed??

Comment: Validate it before saving.

Comment: That's app-level ensurance, I want the db to have it's roll as well in the data integrity.

Comment: If `Laravel` converts the missing values to empty strings then database will allow it because an empty is not `null`.

Comment: Exactly doode, thats what beats me, I don't want larvel to convert it to empty string - that's what u call silent failure. bad. bad. bad.

Comment: That's why you should validate dude :-)

Comment: Dammit. How will I sleep at night..

Comment: It's not Laravel, it's your database.  Try running the query `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` and attempting to use `MyModel::create([]);` again.

Comment: @user3158900 put it in an answer. now!

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($model) {
            static::setNullWhenEmpty($model);
            return true;
        });
    }

    private static function setNullWhenEmpty($model)
    {
        foreach ($model->toArray() as $name => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $model->{$name} = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Credit:** [Set fields to null instead of empty value to avoid problems with nullable foreign keys](http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/set-fields-to-null-instead-of-empty-value-to-avoid-problems-with-nullable-foreign-keys)